# How to get the title of a playlist from the YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to get the **title of the playlist** from the YouTube API, but I don't know how to do it.

I am already able to get the title of each video in the playlist, but I also wanna get the title of the YT playlist.

This is how I'm currently calling the YT Api:

```
const baseApiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3";
const response = await axios.get(`${baseApiUrl}/playlistItems`, {
            params: {
                part: "snippet",
                maxResults: "50",
                playlistId: playlistId,
                key: apiKey,
                pageToken: nextPageToken,
            },
});
```

I've also tried to find a solution with the help of their documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) but I wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For to obtain the title of a playlist given by its ID, you'll have to invoke the [`Playlists.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) API endpoint queried with the request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#id) set to the respective playlist's ID.

For example, see this playlist that belongs to the well-known news and information programme *DW News*, playlist which is subsumed to Brexit issues: [`Brexit News`](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT6yxVwBEbi22rbp2Mve4yEJVpSJFcC9g).

Querying the API with an URL of form:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=$YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY&id=PLT6yxVwBEbi22rbp2Mve4yEJVpSJFcC9g&part=id,snippet&fields=items(id,snippet(title,channelId,channelTitle))`

will produce the following JSON result:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "PLT6yxVwBEbi22rbp2Mve4yEJVpSJFcC9g",
      "snippet": {
        "channelId": "UCknLrEdhRCp1aegoMqRaCZg",
        "title": "Brexit News",
        "channelTitle": "DW News"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that above I used the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter for to get from the API a reduced set of info of the [whole playlist metadata available](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#resource-representation).

Comment: Thanks for sharing API. Working fine as expected.

Comment: For me, im looking for the Plalylist title, not the channel title. The channel title the same for all playlists. The simple title is the video title. If i go to my channel to view only the playlist without playing theme, there is a Playlist title that i do not see in the Youtue api results.